# What is the force in pounds that gallium exerts when it expands?

Tags: forces, material-science, estimation

I need to know a estimate on how many pounds 100 grams of gallium solidifying from its liquid state would exert if there was something stopping it. I don't need all the math as I only know algebra-II

Comment: -1 No research effort. ... After some mindful thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Around room temperature, the density of solid gallium (Ga-I) is about 5.91 g/cm$^3$ (although this depends on the pressure - at higher pressures, Ga-II, the tetragonal form, becomes the stable phase - and it has a much higher density (about 5.7% higher than Ga-I). See for example [Lyapin et al, 2008](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S1063776108110125) ); [the density of the liquid phase](https://www.aqua-calc.com/page/density-table/substance/liquid-blank-gallium) is 6.094 g/cm$^3$. That means that the volume wants to change by about 3%.

The bulk modulus of solid gallium is between 44 and 68 GPa. To achieve a strain of 3%, you need a pressure that is 3% of 50 GPa, or about 1.5 GPa, of 15000 atm. At that pressure you might be converting part of the solid to the Ga-II phase; the result is that your material will find itself at the triple point, where the equilibrium pressure is **1.24 GPa** (see Lyapin et al, link above).

It seems to me that you'll be hard pushed to contain it... like water turning to ice, it can exert a LOT of pressure.

Note - you asked about "force". That is of course pressure times area. If we assume your 100 g of gallium to be a cube, it would have a side of about 2.5 cm. The force on one side of this cube (area about 6 cm$^2$) would be about 800 kN, or 1.8 million pounds of force.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question and not just mindlessly downvoting it.